# Notepad++ right-click to open file in a new window

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, notepad++, regedit

How can I configure Notepad++ to open a file in a new window when I right-click it and select `Edit with Notepad++` ? I already know I have to launch the program with the `-multiInst` switch, I just don't know how to add that to the registry mapping for the right-click.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/4696706

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to fix the right-click behavior of "Edit with Notepad++", first go to:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Notepad++
```

If the default value is:

```
{00F3C2EC-A6EE-11DE-A03A-EF8F55D89593}
```

then go to:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00F3C2EC-A6EE-11DE-A03A-EF8F55D89593}\Settings
```

Among the items should be `Custom REG_SZ` and nothing after it. Change the value to `-nosession -multiInst`.

It should now read `Custom REG_SZ -nosession -multiInst`. If you already have custom arguments defined, then just add a space and append `-nosession -multiInst` to the list.

**References**

- [Context Menu - Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Context_Menu)
- [Multiple Instances - Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Multiple_Instances)
- [Extending Shortcut Menus (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144101.aspx)
- [Shell.ShellExecute method (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Default Programs (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Context Menu link broken, see https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/shell-extension/

Answer (score 0):

I use a 2016 version of the NotePad++ installer. It natively includes Plugin Manager, context menu support and right click > Open of many files without any issues.

After installing, I go to Help > Update and the helpful settings remain in the upgrade.